# backtesting.py finding the best values for Annual Return, SQN, Win Rate, Final Equity or other

Tags: python, pandas, finance, back-testing

Backtesting.py produces an object of the following type:backtesting._stats._Stats. I'm using three different methods (RSI, 4 moving averages, skopt) to determine Annual Return, SQN, Win Rate, Final Equity in three different instances of stats. stats_RSI, stats_Sma4, stats_skopt. I would like to reference Annual Return, SQN, Win Rate, Final Equity and have a summary of which method produces the best result for each (highest values). Now I do this empirically:

```
#Comparison of all methods 
print('\033[1m' + 'Method 1: RSI' + '\033[0m''\nAnnual Return: ',round(stats_RSI["Return (Ann.) [%]"],2),
  '\nSortino Ratio: ',round(stats_RSI["Sortino Ratio"],2), '\nSQN: ',
  round(stats_RSI["SQN"],2),'\nWin Rate: ',round(stats_RSI["Win Rate [%]"],2),
  '\nFinal Equity: ',round(stats_RSI["Equity Final [$]"],2))

print('\033[1m' + '\nMethod 2: Moving Averages'+ '\033[0m''\nAnnual Return: ',round(stats_Sma4["Return (Ann.) [%]"],2),
  '\nSortino Ratio: ',round(stats_Sma4["Sortino Ratio"],2), '\nSQN: ',
  round(stats_Sma4["SQN"],2),'\nWin Rate: ',round(stats_Sma4["Win Rate [%]"],2),
  '\nFinal Equity: ',round(stats_Sma4["Equity Final [$]"],2))

print('\033[1m' + '\nMethod 3: Scikit Optimize'+ '\033[0m''\nAnnual Return: ',round(stats_skopt["Return (Ann.) [%]"],2),
  '\nSortino Ratio: ',round(stats_skopt["Sortino Ratio"],2), '\nSQN: ',
  round(stats_skopt["SQN"],2),'\nWin Rate: ',round(stats_skopt["Win Rate [%]"],2),
  '\nFinal Equity: ',round(stats_skopt["Equity Final [$]"],2))
```

which produces:

```
Method 1: RSI
Annual Return:  16.82 
Sortino Ratio:  1.06 
SQN:  2.77 
Win Rate:  82.35 
Final Equity:  37628.0

Method 2: Moving Averages
Annual Return:  4.23 
Sortino Ratio:  0.35 
SQN:  0.73 
Win Rate:  41.27 
Final Equity:  14240.32

Method 3: Scikit Optimize
Annual Return:  13.73 
Sortino Ratio:  1.25 
SQN:  1.69 
Win Rate:  47.62 
Final Equity:  29941.38
```

I would like to automatically reference the best value for each category with a reference to the method used for obtaining that value. Each method is saved in its own object (stats_RSI,stats_Sma4,stats_skopt). I have looked at compare(), and max() but I'm not sure how to integrate to obtain best values for each category with a reference to the method used. The idea is to then let the human pick the method according to the value central to a given investment strategy.

Here is what backtesting produces for stats:

```
Start                     2004-08-19 00:00:00
End                       2013-03-01 00:00:00
Duration                   3116 days 00:00:00
Exposure Time [%]                   38.500931
Equity Final [$]                    29941.377
Equity Peak [$]                   35721.40136
Return [%]                          199.41377
Buy & Hold Return [%]              703.458242
Return (Ann.) [%]                    13.73011
Volatility (Ann.) [%]               19.395026
Sharpe Ratio                         0.707919
Sortino Ratio                        1.254814
Calmar Ratio                         0.461043
Max. Drawdown [%]                  -29.780538
Avg. Drawdown [%]                   -3.864038
Max. Drawdown Duration     1942 days 00:00:00
Avg. Drawdown Duration       86 days 00:00:00
# Trades                                   42
Win Rate [%]                        47.619048
Best Trade [%]                      55.580827
Worst Trade [%]                     -5.446038
Avg. Trade [%]                       2.684772
Max. Trade Duration         111 days 00:00:00
Avg. Trade Duration          28 days 00:00:00
Profit Factor                        3.486524
Expectancy [%]                       3.170025
SQN                                    1.6908
_strategy                 Sma4Cross(n1=44,...
_equity_curve                            E...
_trades                       Size  EntryB...
dtype: object
```

I would like to obtain something like:

```
Annual Return: 16.82 stats_rsi
Sortino Ratio: 1.25 stats_skopt
SQN: 2.77 stats_rsi
Win Rate: 82.35 stats_rsi
Final Equity: 37628.0 stats_rsi
```

EDIT

I did this:

```
methods = [stats_RSI, stats_Sma4, stats_skopt]
annual_return = 0
sortino_ratio = 0
sqn = 0
win_rate = 0
final_equity = 0
for method in methods:
   if method["Return (Ann.) [%]"] > annual_return:
       annual_return = method["Return (Ann.) [%]"]
       print("Annual Return:\n", annual_return, "\n", method._strategy, "\n")
   if method["Sortino Ratio"] > sortino_ratio:
        sortino_ratio = method["Sortino Ratio"]
        print("Sortino Ratio:\n", sortino_ratio, "\n", method._strategy, "\n")
   if method["SQN"] > sqn:
       sqn = method["SQN"]
       print("SQN:\n", sqn, "\n", method._strategy, "\n")
   if method["Win Rate [%]"] > win_rate:
       win_rate = method["Win Rate [%]"]
       print("Win Rate:\n", win_rate, "\n", method._strategy, "\n")
   if method["Equity Final [$]"] > final_equity:
       final_equity = method["Equity Final [$]"]
        print("Final Equity:\n", final_equity, "\n", method._strategy, "\n")
```

Obtaining:
Annual Return:
16.820232474460074.
RsiOscillator(upper_bound=70,lower_bound=35,rsi_window=14).

Sortino Ratio:
1.058212866533837.
RsiOscillator(upper_bound=70,lower_bound=35,rsi_window=14)

SQN:
2.7697514727638506.
RsiOscillator(upper_bound=70,lower_bound=35,rsi_window=14).

Win Rate:
82.35294117647058.
RsiOscillator(upper_bound=70,lower_bound=35,rsi_window=14).

Final Equity:
37628.0.
RsiOscillator(upper_bound=70,lower_bound=35,rsi_window=14).

Sortino Ratio:
1.2548141815003493.
Sma4Cross(n1=44,n2=134,n_enter=39,n_exit=27).

but I'm sure there's a better way with **less lines of code**...

EDIT 2
See slothrop's answer below (thanks). His approach is environment friendly with an execution time of 863 µs whereas mine took 15.5 ms to execute. This community is very special and I appreciate all the talent animating its generosity and willingness to share knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
result_objs = {'RSI': stats_RSI, 'SMA4': stats_SMA4, 'SKOpt': stats_skopt}
metrics = ['annual_return', 'sortino_ratio', 'sqn', 'win_rate', 'final_equity']

for metric in metrics:
   results_by_method = {k: getattr(v, metric) for k, v in result_objs.items()}
   best_method, best_result = max(results_by_method.items(), key=lambda t: t[-1])
   print(f'{metric}: {best_result} (from {best_method})')
```

Comment: Yeah, now that's programming. Thanks! I just changed:
    metrics = ['Return (Ann.) [%]', 'Sortino Ratio', 'SQN', 'Win Rate [%]', 'Equity Final [$]'] and stats_SMA4 to stats_Sma4 to be inline with parameters. Could you explain the mechanics? You're creating a dictionary with the series, you then define a list object containing the attributes in those series and...

Comment: ...then we loop over the attributes we care about.  For each attribute, (1) we build a dictionary `results_by_method` where the key is the name of the stats object and the value is the result of retrieving the attribute from that stats object, (2) we get the maximum value from the items in that dictionary.  Because `.items()` returns (key, value) tuples, we have to tell Python what we mean by the max: we want it to be based on the last element in the tuple, i.e. the value of the attribute

Comment: now it's clear and quite fundamental to problems similar where you have to compare values over multiple series

Comment: question should be changed to: Python: Finding best values over multiple series